# Equivalent definition of left hand limit.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $F$ be a Banach space. Let $f : [a,b] \longrightarrow F$ be a function. Then $L$ is said to be the left hand limit of $f$ at $c \in (a, b]$ if for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (c-\delta, c)$ we have $\|f(x) - L\|_{F} \lt \varepsilon.$

This is the definition I am familiar with from my school days. But while taking up a course in several variable calculus in normed linear spaces in the masters I find a new definition of it which says that $f$ is said to have a left hand limit at $c$ if for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any pair of points $s,t \in (c - \delta,c)$ we have $\|f(s) - f(t)\|_{F} \lt \varepsilon.$

I have proved the former definition implies the later one. But I cannot able to prove the reverse implication. From the later definition how do I get hold of the limit of the former definition? Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the same: Take any constant function and redefine it at one point. Or more generally (to answer your comment), it fails at any left-side jump discontinuity.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro do you mean jump discontinuity at one point?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I didn't get your point. Consider the function $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x & \quad 0 \leq x \lt \frac {1} {2} \\
            1 & \quad \frac {1} {2} \leq x \leq 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ What is the problem then? Then the left hand limit of $f$ at $\frac {1} {2}$ is $\frac {1} {2}.$ For any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ if we take $\delta = \varepsilon$ then we are through for the later definition.

Comment: this slightly resembles continuity vs uniform continuity in regards to how the quantifies are set up.

Comment: *What is the problem then?* --- Sorry, I was involved with something else and didn't pay close enough attention. I was thinking of left continuity at a point not being implied by left continuity at all points in some open left neighborhood of that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(s_n)_n$ a sequence valued in $[a,b]$ such that $s_n$ converges toward $c$ by the left (in the usual sense for real sequences).

Now, using your latter definition, for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we can easily see that there exists $N_0$ such as

$$\|f(s_p) - f(s_q)\|_{F} \lt \varepsilon, \quad \forall p,q>N_0 \quad \quad (1)$$

This means exactly that the sequence $(f(s_n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $F$. Since $F$ is a Banach space, this prove that there exists $L$ such as the sequence $(f(s_n))_n$ converges toward $L$ in $F$.

I believe it should be easy to conclude from here, I'll let you write the details !

Comment: Suppose $f$ has a left hand limit at $c \in (a,b]$ according to latter definition then given any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any pair of points $s,t \in (c - \delta,c) \cap [a,b]$ we have $\|f(s) - f(t)\|_{F} \lt \varepsilon.$ Choose $n \in \Bbb N$ sufficiently large so that $s_n \in (c - \delta,c)$ and $\|f(s_n) - L\|_{F} \lt \frac {\varepsilon} {2}.$ Then for all $x \in (c - \delta, c) \cap [a,b]$ we have $$\|f(x) - L\|_{F} \leq \|f(x) - f(s_n)\|_{F} + \|f(s_n) - L\|_{F} \lt \frac {\varepsilon} {2} + \frac {\varepsilon} {2} = \varepsilon$$   Am I right?

Comment: Yes that seems perfect !